# Finding the constant values of an equation, such that variance is 1 and expected value is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

[image]

Hello, so I think I did this correctly, but I just want to make sure. For the expected value, I just did the linearity of expectation which is $E[Y] = aE[X] + b = aμ + b$.

That deduces to $b = 0$

Now for the variance, I used the well-known variance formula $(+)=2$. So that is $1 = a^2$ (1) which means a would have to be 1.

I know this may be simple, but I am brand new to stats, so I need to get my fundamentals down

Comment: How do you get $b=0$? Note that $\mu \neq 0$ is possible. And $var(X)=1$ is also not true. That is $\sigma^2$. But your formulas seem to be in good shape, but it seems that your application of the theorems is a bit off.

Comment: Ok, so I see what you mean. I actually had a = 1/σ. and b = -1/σE[x]. I need to brush up on my algebra. Havent taken a math course since highschool calculus and I am in  a high level econometrics program.

Comment: Ah yes, then you'd need to brush up for sure. But you are doing well, if you are coming here I suppose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to solve the problem is to Standardize $X$. Thus the r.v.

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
Y=\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

is distributed with mean zero and variance 1.

It is easy to look at (1) in the following way

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
Y=\frac{1}{\sigma_X}\cdot X-\frac{\mu_X}{\sigma_X}=aX+b
\
}
$$

thus

$$a=\frac{1}{\sigma_X}$$

and

$$b=-\frac{\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$$

In my opinion this is the best way you can solve your problem in a Statistical way of thinking